# git latest state does not match most recent change in history

Tags: git

I have an unusual situation with my private git repo that I didn't think was possible.

On a certain remote branch, I found a certain file that has been modified over time with multiple checkins by various developers and have also been modified through merges with different branches which made commits to this file over time.

I noticed that with this particular file, the contents of the file doesn't match the most recent commit in history for that file. This means that, the most recent commit in history on the remote server says that this file had some particular content modifications. But, when I look at the latest state of that file, those particular content modifications aren't incorporated.

I didn't think this kind of inconsistency was possible with Git. I thought Git tracked all changes for all files in its history.

What could have caused such an inconsistency?

We have thousands of files in the git repo. Are there commands that I can use to see if the most recent commits for all the files in our repo match the latest state?

Comment: Have you pulled the latest for that branch?

Comment: How are you viewing the file history? Reason I ask is that we're facing a somewhat similar issue with BitBucket.

Comment: You can use `git blame` command to know the changes you have in the file, with the commit and the user who did it.

Comment: Git doesn't have "remote branch(es)", though it does call some names *remote-tracking branch names* (which I think is a little misleading). What really matters in Git, though, is *commits*. Commits contain snapshots, and identify their previous or *parent* commits; comparing commits to their parents is how you derive the history. The true name of any given commit is its hash ID. Branch names and remote-tracking names merely serve as ways to spell the hash IDs (since the IDs themselves are big, ugly, and not useful to humans).

Answer (score 0):

> What could have caused such an inconsistency?

In our case it was caused solving a conflict. In the process of solving the conflict the file was reverted to the previous state. Git history still displayed the newest commit that changed the file, but the contents of the file didn't match this commit.

> How to find this out?

Look for all commits in the repository and search for the file within those commits.